# Remove properties set by "troubleshoot compability"

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257110/can-you-force-visual-studio-to-always-run-as-an-administrator-in-windows-8) guide in order to make Visual Studio always be run as administrator. However, I screwed it up and it is not working any longer ever since. I even tried to reinstall the whole application but the changes made from the troubleshoot program remain and thus it still is messy. Any good ideas?

Comment: The accepted answer has a revert solution listed in the comments. Did you try it?

Comment: Be specific what step didn't you complete?

Comment: I believe you have to modify the devenv.exe for visual studio correct?  If you right click the devenv executable, and select properties, one of the tabs should be capability.  You might be able to change the settings back in this tab?  In your case, it should just be unchecking the "Run this program as an administrator" checkbox if thats all you changed.

Comment: @TimmyJim unfortunately, this is not the case. That's why I asked here.

Comment: So what exactly happens when you try to run Visual Studio?  Also, which version of Visual Studio?